# Reuse Magento product list block - custom collection

Tags: php, magento

I want to use the default magento product list block and template but use it with my own custom product collection.

The collection is not part of a category, but a collection that is being created by my own module.

how do i tie the two up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own block class, inheriting from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, and to override at least its `_getProductCollection()` method, to make it load your collection.

And regarding the template, you can assign the default one to your block in your layout definition.